# post calling api using dio gives 404 flutter

Tags: http, flutter, flutter-dependencies, dio

I am calling api from flutter which is post type, but it gives me error 404, can figure out what is the issue

```
class OtpVerifyApi {
  Future otpVerifyAPI(OtpVerifyRequest otpVerifyRequest, String token) async {
    return NetworkCommon.getClient(Constants.apiEndPoint)
        .post("otp",
            data: otpVerifyRequest.toMap(),
            options: new Options(headers: {"Authorization": token}))
        .then((response) {
      return response.data;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print("onError " + onError.toString());
    });
  }
}

class OtpVerifyRequest {
  String otp;

  toMap() {
    return {"otp": this.otp};
  }
}



verfiyUser(OtpVerifyRequest otpVerifyRequest, String token) async {
    _memoizer.runOnce(() =>
        OtpVerifyApi().otpVerifyAPI(otpVerifyRequest, token).then((reponse) {
          OtpVerifyResponse otpVerifyResponse =
              OtpVerifyResponse.fromJson(reponse);
          print("otpVerifyResponse $otpVerifyResponse");

        }).catchError((error) {
          hideLoader();
          print("otp error: $error");
        }));
  }
```

These are my three source files, 1st one is my client , 2nd one is my requestbody and 3rd one is where i am getting its response.
Help me to figure this out. 
Thanks in advance.

```
Future<OtpVerifyResponse> verifyUser(
      OtpVerifyRequest otpVerifyRequest, String token) async {
    Map<String, String>  requestHeaders = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
      };
    return http
        .post(Constants.apiEndPoint + "registration/_verify",
            body: otpVerifyRequest.toMap(), headers: requestHeaders)
        .then((http.Response response) {
      hideLoader();
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      print("statusCode" + statusCode.toString());
      print("response ${json.decode(response.body)}");
      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
        hideLoader();
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return OtpVerifyResponse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    });
  }
```

I also tried this http method but it also doesnt work not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: An http 404 error means your resource is not found on server. You could check your url  in debug mode to understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class OtpVerifyApi {
  Future otpVerifyAPI(OtpVerifyRequest otpVerifyRequest, String token) async {
    return NetworkCommon.getClient(Constants.apiEndPoint)
        .post("otp",
            data: otpVerifyRequest.toMap(),
            options: new Options(headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"}))
        .then((response) {
      return response.data;
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print("onError " + onError.toString());
    });
  }
}
```

I was passing the authorization token wrong way..took a while to figure it out :)